# In Airflow, how do you get a parent tasks, task_id?

Tags: airflow

I have a branch task that relies on an XCOM set by it's direct upstream.  The upstream task id's are generated via loop such as task_1, task_2..task_n.
So something like this:

```
task_n >> branch[task_a, task_b]
```

Is there a way for a branch to access an XCOM set by it's direct upstream?  I know I could use op_kwargs and pass the task id to the branch.  I just wanted to see if there was a more Airflow native way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean `ask_n >> branch >> [task_a, task_b]`?

Comment: Do you want that `task_a` and `task_b` get a value from `task_n` or do you want that `branch` gets a value from `task_n`?

Comment: Either branch gets the value from task_n or I need "branch" to be able to identify the task id of task_n, so I can retrieve an XCOM set by task_n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PythonBranchOperator` should be created with `provide_context=True` and the python callable for it can look something like this:

```
def branch_callable(task_instance, task, **kwargs):
    upstream_ids = task.upstream_task_ids  # an iterable
    xcoms = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=upstream_ids)
    # process the xcoms of the direct upstream tasks
```